# Objects in JavaScript defined and undefined at the same time (in a FireFox extension)

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am chasing down a [bug](https://www.mozdev.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22480) in a FireFox extension. I've finally managed to see it for myself (I've only had reports before) and I can't understand how what I saw is possible.

One error message from my extension in the Error Console is "gBrowser is not defined". This by itself would be surprising enough, since the overlay is over browser.xul and navigator.xul, and I expect `gBrowser` to be available from both. Even worse is the actual place where it happens: line 101 of [nextplease.js](http://gist.github.com/311567). That is, inside the function `isTopLevelDocument`, which is only called from `onContentLoaded`, which is only called from `onLoad` here:

```
gBrowser.addEventListener(this.loadType, function (event) {
    nextplease.loadListener.onContentLoaded(event);
},
true);
```

So `gBrowser` is defined in `onLoad`, but somehow undefined in `isTopLevelDocument`.

When I tried to actually use the extension, I got another error: "nextplease is not defined". The interesting thing is that it happened on lines 853 and 857. That is, *inside* the functions

```
nextplease.getNextLink = function () {
    nextplease.getLink(window.content, nextplease.NextPhrasesMap, nextplease.NextImagesMap, nextplease.isNextRegExp, nextplease.NEXT_SEARCH_TYPE);
}

nextplease.getPrevLink = function () {
    nextplease.getLink(window.content, nextplease.PrevPhrasesMap, nextplease.PrevImagesMap, nextplease.isPrevRegExp, nextplease.PREV_SEARCH_TYPE);
}
```

So `nextplease` is somehow defined enough to call these functions, but isn't defined inside them.

Finally, executing `typeof(nextplease)` in Execute JS returns "object". Same for `gBrowser`.

How can this happen? Any ideas?

Comment: Well, the context in which that code initially runs is not necessarily the same as the context in which the various defined functions run. (I'm not a XUL developer so I'm just working from first principles.)  What would happen if you stashed "gBrowser" and "nextplease" into the "nextplease" object itself?  Or in a closure surrounding the definitions?

Comment: @Pointy: Very good point indeed. This could turn out to be a fine example of why global variables are bad. A closure could be the way to go here...

Comment: Is it possible that your code is accidentally running in the document, or in content, rather than in chrome ?

That might cause gBrowser to suddenly be undefined, as it is not exposed to content.

Comment: That seems like the only reasonable idea so far. Is there a simple (or not so simple) way to test in a function whether it's running in chrome?

Answer (score 2):

For the second case:

```
nextplease.getNextLink = function () {
    nextplease.getLink(window.content, nextplease.NextPhrasesMap, nextplease.NextImagesMap, nextplease.isNextRegExp, nextplease.NEXT_SEARCH_TYPE);
}

nextplease.getPrevLink = function () {
    nextplease.getLink(window.content, nextplease.PrevPhrasesMap, nextplease.PrevImagesMap, nextplease.isPrevRegExp, nextplease.PREV_SEARCH_TYPE);
}
```

I'd try this instead:

```
nextplease.getNextLink = function () {
    this.getLink(window.content, this.NextPhrasesMap, this.NextImagesMap, this.isNextRegExp, this.NEXT_SEARCH_TYPE);
}

nextplease.getPrevLink = function () {
    this.getLink(window.content, this.PrevPhrasesMap, this.PrevImagesMap, this.isPrevRegExp, this.PREV_SEARCH_TYPE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's happening (in which context the code is running and therefore why it's not seeing the gbrowser and other global variables) but an easy workaround for gbrowser being undefined would be to get a reference to the main window and access it from there:

```
var mainWindow = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                     .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation)
                     .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
                     .rootTreeItem
                     .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                     .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);

mainWindow.gbrowser.addEventListener( ... )
```

This should work independently of the context where the code is running since you would not rely on global variables.