# Function values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures

`nextplease.init = function() {...}` is a function with no arguments. I'd expect `nextplease.init` and 
`function() {nextplease.init();}` to behave identically. Is there any possible difference between them (obviously, you can assign something to `nextplease.init`, but let's exclude that)?
In particular, can there be a difference in behavior between `window.addEventListener("load", nextplease.init, false);` and `window.addEventListener("load", function() {nextplease.init();}, false);`?

The bug I'm trying to find is described in [Objects in JavaScript defined and undefined at the same time (in a FireFox extension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314961/objects-in-javascript-defined-and-undefined-at-the-same-time-in-a-firefox-extens) Someone has suggested that using the first form instead of the second might make a difference.

Comment: Actually in JS one can access arguments by the `arguments` variable, so we cannot reliably tell how many arguments a function would take.

Comment: True, but that's not done in this case. I'll provide a link to code.

Comment: The second one will create a new execution context in which nextplease.init() will be executed. The scope chain/execution context stack will therefore be one larger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One important difference is the value of the "this" keyword inside the body of the function referenced by nextplease.init.

Assume nextplease is defined as such:

```
nextplease = {};
nextplease.someCustomProperty = "hello";
nextplease.init = function () { alert(this.someCustomProperty); }
```

In the first example, the value of "this" would be the DOM object, and the alert would fail:

```
window.addEventListener("load", nextplease.init, false);
```

In the second form, the value of "this" would be the nextplease object, and the alert would say, "hello":

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {nextplease.init();}, false);
```

Reference the MDC documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible differences

```
window.addEventListener("load", nextplease.init, false);
```

This will call the function and that is all.  If you wanted to add parameters, then this wouldn't be able to set them.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {nextplease.init();}, false);
```

This, on the other hand, allows you to call more than one function, and allows you to set parameters.  It also adds extra overhead of calling a function, and storing a function in memory.

Answer (score 0):

These two:

```
window.addEventListener("load", nextplease.init, false); 
window.addEventListener("load", function() {nextplease.init();}, false);?
```

are *almost* exactly the same, assuming `nextplease.init` is a function object.

The one difference is that in the second case, any arguments passed to the outer function (even though its signature doesn't define any, they can still be passed) will not get passed to `nextplease.init()`. But since this is just going through the `addEventListener` API, you know what will be passed ahead of time.